# Swagger UI Displays but I get an "ERROR" indicator

Tags: java, asp.net, swagger

My swagger UI displays and it is showing all of my routes. Everything looks great except there is a big red ERROR indicator on the lower right. When I click it I get:

```
{
  "schemaValidationMessages":[ 
     {
       "level":"error",
       "message":"Can't read from file http://devxxxx.com:80/swagger/docs/v1"
     }
   ]
}
```

[image]

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 6):

That's the validator badge.  The error is most likely because the on-line validator can't reach the OpenAPI spec on your server (devxxxx.com).  I am assuming this server is behind a firewall.

Depending on the version of Swagger UI, you may be able to disable the validator badge.  In 2.x, you can simply add `validatorUrl: null` to the `SwaggerUi` constructor in `index.html`.  In 3.x, there have been problems disabling the validator badge.  For more details search for [validatorUrl issues](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20validatorUrl) over on GitHub.

Comment: `validatorUrl: null` is supported in Swagger UI 3.0.4+.

Answer (score 0):

"validatorUrl: null" solution still works in 2020.  I didn't have validatorURL in my SwaggerUIBundle but I just added it and the error no longer shows now.

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: window.location.href.replace('swagger-ui.html','service/swagger.json'),
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    validatorUrl: null,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
```