# Swagger UI displays Error still after using validatorUrl as null

Tags: java, swagger, dropwizard

Though the scenario, if I was to describe, is similar to 
[Swagger UI Displays but I get an "ERROR" indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129035/swagger-ui-displays-but-i-get-an-error-indicator). Everything works fine for me, my routes are listed properly, but the Error is displayed and the solution suggested on all such similar threads is pertaining to setting `validationUrl=null`.

I am using the following dependencies -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.federecio</groupId>
    <artifactId>dropwizard-swagger</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is what my register code looks like -

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<CustomServiceConfig> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new SwaggerBundle<CustomServiceConfig>() {

        @Override
        protected SwaggerBundleConfiguration getSwaggerBundleConfiguration(
                CustomServiceConfig customServiceConfig) {
            return customServiceConfig.getSwaggerBundleConfiguration();
        }
    });
}
```

where these configuration in the ***`config.yml`*** are -

```
swagger:
  title: Custom Service
  description: APIs for Test
  contact: me@alias.com
  uriPrefix: /
  resourcePackage: com.x.y.package
```

I've tried updating the [SwaggerBundleConfiguration](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger/blob/master/src/main/java/io/federecio/dropwizard/swagger/SwaggerBundleConfiguration.java) in the above `.yml` to add

```
validatorUrl=null
```

But this doesn't seem to be fixing the issue either. How can this be solved?

Comment: which version of the swagger UI are you using?

Comment: @Phil I haven't specified any. Is there a way to check or customize the swagger UI version when used through dropwizard?

Comment: let me know if my answer helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting `validatorURL: null` into the constructor for the swagger ui has to happen *in the swagger `index.html` file*, not the Dropwizard yaml configuration file [[see the SO post you referenced]](http://Swagger%20UI%20Displays%20but%20I%20get%20an%20%22ERROR%22%20indicator).

So you have a couple options, but to start I wouldn't recommend the `dropwizard-swagger` package because it seems to have fallen rather far behind Dropwizard itself. According to the [version documentation on its page](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger#version-matrix), it only supports up to Dropwizard 0.8 and swagger-ui 2.4. Dropwizard is at 1.x and the swagger-ui 3.x.

### Option 1

If you do away with the `dropwizard-swagger` lib you can put the swagger-ui assets directly into your project under resources directory and add an `AssetBundle` to your Dropwizard application. [This bundle allows serving of static content on your classpath](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/v1.1.2/dropwizard-assets/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/assets/AssetsBundle.java#L30). The static html you'll need is all in the [`dist` folder here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) (i.e. copy it to /resources in your dropwizard project).

You'd have something like

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<CustomServiceConfig> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/swagger", "/swagger", "index.html"));
}
```

which will serve the swagger UI on `localhost:<port>/swagger` like the `dropwizard-swagger` lib does.

For this solution to work, you'll need to generate the swagger json file as well and put that into the correct path in your build directory (resources path too). [The `swagger-maven-plugin` can help do this for you.](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin) [Here is a link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/758) to some discussion around how to bundle the static swagger ui and swagger json in your app. You'll need to modify the `index.html` to point at your swagger json file. [The line of code is here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html#L77).

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "/path/relative/to/your/java/jar/swagger-api.json",
    validatorUrl: null,
    ...
}
```

### Option 2

You can fork the `dropwizard-swagger` code, modify the `index.html` file that is include to have `validatorUrl: null` set. The place you need to add this is in the constructor for the `SwaggerUI` js object. You can [see it here](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger/blob/master/src/main/resources/swagger-static/index.html#L33).

In brief:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: url,
    validatorUrl: null,
    ...
}
```

You'll then need to rebuild the library and include in your project this modified version of `dropwizard-swagger` library. Note that the `dropwizard-swagger` project [just happens to create an `AssetBundle` for you](https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger/blob/master/src/main/java/io/federecio/dropwizard/swagger/SwaggerBundle.java#L57).

### Summary

Either way you'll need to modify the index.html file that is part of the swagger ui distribution. The easiest way forward may be to just ignore the error icon for now.

Comment: Thanks! This helps.